# android- force close by launching application on Android lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've written an application and now when I want to launch it on **Android 5**, it launches on other versions of Android perfectly and I don't get any error from those but I get these errors on **Android Lollipop**:

```
[07-03 07:57:35.780  2955: 2955 I/] debuggerd: Nov  6 2015 06:54:22
07-03 07:57:42.193 2966-2966/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-03 07:57:42.193 2966-2966/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-03 08:02:10.113 2997-2997/com.android.settings E/InstalledAppDetails: Exception when retrieving package:ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:114)
    at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.retrieveAppEntry(InstalledAppDetails.java:658)
    at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.refreshUi(InstalledAppDetails.java:692)
    at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.onActivityResult(InstalledAppDetails.java:564)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3535)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
07-03 08:02:44.704 3130-3130/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-03 08:02:44.704 3130-3130/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-03 08:03:08.141 3159-3159/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-03 08:03:08.141 3159-3159/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-03 08:03:08.307 981-981/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 981: eglCreateSyncKHR(1181): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
07-03 08:03:12.348 3173-3207/ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf6f7446e in tid 3207 (pool-1-thread-1)
07-03 08:03:14.153 1022-1847/system_process E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
07-03 08:03:14.187 1022-1062/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '34b7e9a4 ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners/ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-03 08:03:14.251 981-981/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 981: eglCreateSyncKHR(1181): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
07-03 08:03:15.113 250-250/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/3173/oom_score_adj; errno=2
07-03 08:03:19.860 3252-3290/ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf6f7446e in tid 3290 (pool-1-thread-1)
07-03 08:03:20.676 1022-1847/system_process E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
07-03 08:03:46.265 3349-3349/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-03 08:03:46.265 3349-3349/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-03 08:03:46.308 981-981/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 981: eglCreateSyncKHR(1181): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
07-03 08:03:50.627 3363-3409/ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf6f7446e in tid 3409 (pool-1-thread-1)
07-03 08:03:53.470 1022-1098/system_process E/NativeCrashListener: Exception dealing with report
android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
    at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:147)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:230)
    at android.system.Os.read(Os.java:364)
    at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.consumeNativeCrashData(NativeCrashListener.java:240)
    at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.run(NativeCrashListener.java:138)
07-03 08:03:53.503 1022-1062/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '1019e92 ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners/ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-03 08:03:53.504 1022-1847/system_process E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
07-03 08:03:55.910 3445-3481/ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf6f7446e in tid 3481 (pool-1-thread-1)
07-03 08:03:56.288 1022-1847/system_process E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
07-03 08:03:56.335 1022-1062/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '88a8b24 ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners/ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners.FistActiivty (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-03 08:03:56.336 1022-1062/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'fcd7eb6 ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners/ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners.FistActiivty (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-03 08:03:56.735 1022-3509/system_process E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 384x384
07-03 08:04:03.840 3521-3558/ir.mazandaran.persiandesigners A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf6f7446e in tid 3558 (pool-1-thread-1)
07-03 08:04:04.260 1022-1847/system_process E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
07-03 08:08:57.044 81-81/? E/Genyd: recv() error
    [ 07-03 08:08:57.044    81:   81 E/] Socket read error
    [ 07-03 08:08:57.044    81:   81 D/] Socket deconnection
01-01 00:00:00.000 0-0/? E/Internal: device not found
```

Comment: Are you using Multidex functionality ?

Comment: some source code would definitely help